# How to powder silica gel?

Tags: pest-control

We are having serious cockroach problem. I was advised to mix silica gel and boric acid and powder the surfaces where roaches come in. I can't find the silica gel in powder form in my location. I can buy them as crystals in bulk.

I am thinking of using a small mixer grinder jar to powder the crystals. But, I am not sure if it works.

What would be best method to crush silica gel crystals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desiccant silica gel is not all that tough. A spinning blade coffee grinder, or a blender should work. When you get it down to powder, leave the top on for 5-10 minutes. The dust will be awful. You shouldn't dull the blades much, unless you make a habit of this. Mortar and pestle would work too, but for the quantities you'll need would probably be tiresome.

Comment: Will give a try. As @DrMoishe commented, I am exploring the safety issues.

Comment: Come to think of it, last time I had to do something like this, I did it outside, on a breezy day. Doesn't keep dust down, but it keeps it away from you. This is also the preferred method for grinding up Horseradish root. That *will* drive you out of the kitchen.

Comment: I have decided against grinding the silica gel due to safety concerns. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Grinding silica is *not* safe, since [silicosis](https://www.lung.org/lung-health-and-diseases/lung-disease-lookup/silicosis/silicosis-symptoms-causes-risk.html) is a hazard! You can [buy](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Garden-Safe-Brand-Diatomaceous-Earth-4-lb-Insect-Killer/3276739) silica in the form of [diatomaceous earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth), AKA "diatomite" and kieselgur, which is sold as an insecticide (and is also used as a swimming-pool filter and spill-absorbent material).

Interestingly, this fine silica is the remains of microscopic creatures. If you have access to a microscope, take a close [look at these elegant shells](https://www.mccrone.com/the-collecting-cleaning-and-mounting-of-diatoms/)!

Comment: He wants to grind the gel, not silica. Different stuff, no diatoms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silica_gel The stuff is softer than diatomaceous earth. The dust is still fairly nasty.

Comment: @DiMoishe Pippik, thanks for alerting me. I have decided to use only Boric Acid.